# mysqli_fetch_assoc is not working in while loop after upgrade PHP version 5.2 to 7.3

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7.3

I am not sure why this happen because some function is working with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with while loop and some not `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is not working in while loop in a function.

I have used following PHP script

```
function get_customer_record_list($table,$pos_customer){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE pos_customer = '$pos_customer' order by added_date DESC";
        $select =mysqli_query($this->connect,$sql)or die("Query (List) is not executed.");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
            $result [] = $row;
        }
         echo "working";exit();

        //return $result;
    }
```

Not working after closing `while loop` the `$result` value is not print also not display anything after close loop.

There are `501` records in database but data is not print using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` I have also tried `mysqli_fetch_object` with `foreach` loop but data not printing.

I don't know why this happen.

Comment: Do you see `working` being printed? What is `var_dump($select);`?

Comment: No, nothing print after close loop.

Comment: Add `var_dump($select);` before the loop, what do you get?

Comment: By Default MySQLi extension is disabled in PHP 7. You need to enable it from your php.ini file

Comment: @Tushar MySQLi is already enable and i already mentioned in question that some of function is working but not this.

Comment: how you are getting $this->connect

Comment: var_dump($sql) and then var_dump($select) to be sure they are getting or retrieving values. Then upload the result lets see

Comment: could you use if(mysqli_error($this->connect)){die(mysqli_error($this->connect()));} to find what the problem actually is after mysqli_query

Comment: @ShivendraSingh I have mentioned in top section in my current file and other function is working well but this not after while

Comment: check by enabling error logs

Comment: Have you used the exit() function for this example or its a part of the code?

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi, error log enabled but nothing showing only blank page display

Comment: @ShivendraSingh , $this->connect is also working in other function in same file except this function.

Comment: if you are not even getting die() statement means that function may not be called properly

Comment: Ok, No issue in your code when I run without class or function. Last question connect is class variable of function ?

Comment: The example in insufficient - nobody knows how the table is defined, and you also haven't reduced it to trying to select only one column instead of all. Update your question so we see if your table contains TEXT or other big datatypes, and check if selecting distinct columns changes the behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Please check, this should work. I have added the output of the number of rows found and then printed result.

```
function get_customer_record_list($table,$pos_customer){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE pos_customer = '$pos_customer' order by added_date DESC LIMIT 3";
        $select =mysqli_query($this->connect,$sql)or die("Query (List) is not executed.");
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($select);
        echo "Total Rows found-".$rowcount."\n<br>";
        $count=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
            echo "Loop ".$count."\n<br>";
            $count++;

            $result[] = $row;
        }
        echo "Total Iterations -".$count."\n<br>";
        print_r($result);

        //return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Not printing anything after loop

Comment: Total rows 501 but nothing print after end of loop

Comment: Added few more trace logs above, can you please check and let us know the output? As in my case it's working fine

Comment: Now it's showing 3 result but it didn't work without pass limit in query because i have total 501 records.

Comment: It's showing still 105 records but if i set limit greater then 105 it's not work showing blank.I think it should be array index out of bounds ?

Comment: How is your data size? might if you are going out or memory. Please ass ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL); on top of your code